# Android programmatically changes colors to users specs

Tags: android, colors

I currently have my app using a xml style sheet but all the the test users are asking to set their own colors. I can easily get the data for the user but how do I go about changing everything.

I could have a class called after every activity was fired and have it reset the colors based on the user preferences.  is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

COuldn't you use the findViewById(R.id.something) to get the view element from your xml layout

and then you change the colors you want?

(sorry if I misunderstood your question, in this case could you be more specific>-?)

Comment: Yes that is what I am going to do.  But I I would have to put this code on every class that has a UI.  I wonder if there is a way to loop through all of the controls and see what type they are?

Comment: I am just trying to make a generic class to do the work so I dont have to code every object individually

Comment: Why dont you create a ColoredVeiw class that sets its own bg color? then use <com.myapp.ColoredView android:id="@+id/composed"... in the xml layout

Comment: Maybe I just need to tell the users that the colors are the colors and that is the way it is :) I am wanting to set the colors for about 7 objects.  If I could figure out how to update dynamically the styles.xml then it would be easy.